# Select and delete txt files with R

Tags: r

I've got many thousands of .txt files and I want to select files that appear in an excel list I've created. For example, I've got a list of 3 file names:

`001 151`

`023 233`

`310 011`

and I need to find these files names in a folder in Mac, select them, and preferably keep them while deleting the rest. How do I do this in R? Or better still, with some native Mac OS function?

Comment: Once you extract file names from the excel spreadsheet, you can remove the files by calling `file.remove()`.

Comment: Doesn't that remove those files rather than keep them?

Comment: keep is the opposite of remove. So instead of keeping the files you need, you could also remove the files you don't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
All_files = list.files('path/to/folder', recursive = TRUE)

files_to_keep = c('001 151', '023 233', '310 011')

files_to_remove = All_files[!All_files %in% file_to_keep]

files_to_remove_path = paste('path/to/folder', files_to_remove, sep = '/')

unlink(files_to_remove_path, recursive = TRUE)
```

Comment: It seems that when I type files_to_keep = read.xlsx("list_of_names.xlsx", 1, header=F), R treats files_to_keep as a data.frame. I believe your solution works only if the list_of_names is a list of characters like the one in your answer. However, doing something like files_to_keep[] = lapply(files_to_keep, as.character) doesn't seem to work either. Do you have any suggestions how I can coerce the data frame into a character vector?

Comment: Ok I got it, it's files_to_keep = as.vector(files_to_keep$X1). Thanks Veerendra you've been of great help :)